# Rounding float for android

Tags: android, rounding

I want to round float to a given precision. For example:

```
0,6667 to 0,67  
0,004 to 0,00
0,328 to 0,33
```

I know I can round a float to integer, for example:

```
0,06 to 0
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Try using the solution found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the rounding for display or for calculations?

If it's for display you can use this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
float f = (float) 4.234432;
System.out.println(df.format(f));
```

For calculations, you could do it like this:

```
float f = (float) 4.234432;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(f);
bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
f = bd.floatValue();
```

Comment: for display, but I would like to know how to do it for calculations

Comment: Added that one as well. Both methods are quite verbose, but well... it gets it done.

Answer (score 1):

Format a floating point number to a string with a specified number of decimal places using `String.format(...)`.

Example:

```
String.format("%.2f", myFloatingPointValue);
```